# Second bash case statement is used ,even that the first statement is closed by esac

Tags: bash

Issue description :

I  have 2 case statements:

first case is setting a variable in case my argument is `-l`

the second case should set a variable in case my argument is `-P`

but when i am using : `./script -l at`
looks like the second case is also processed and i am getting:
`./script -l at`
"ERROR"

the code is :

```
while getopts ":l:P:h" o; do
  case "${o}" in
  l)
    l=${OPTARG}
    ;;
  P)
    P=${OPTARG}  
    ;;
    h)
    usage
    ;;
  *)
    usage
    ;;
  esac
done

case "$l" in
  "at")
   l="at"
    ;;
  "ab")
    l="ab"
    ;;
  
  *)
    l="ac"
    ;;
esac

case "$P" in
  "an")
   P="an"
    ;;
  "ar")
   P="anr"
    ;;
  *)
    echo "ERROR"
    exit 128
    ;;
esac
```

When i Use -l , i want only the first case to be matched

Answer (score 1):

Your third `case` will throw an error if `P` is unassigned, or set to a value other than `an` or `ar` (which it overrides to `anr`).  If you want to permit `P` to be empty, say so. If you want to require either `l` or `P`, but not both, say so.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

while getopts ":l:P:h" o; do
  case "${o}" in
  l)
    l=${OPTARG}
    ;;
  P)
    P=${OPTARG}  
    ;;
  h)  # note indentation fix
    usage
    ;;
  *)
    usage
    ;;
  esac
done

case "$l" in
  "at" | "ab" )   # notice collapsing of two options, and skip of no-op code
    ;;
  '')  # notice addition of empty case
    ;;
  *)
    l="ac"
    ;;
esac

case "$P" in
  "an")
   P="an"
    ;;
  "ar")
   P="anr"
    ;;
  *)  # only fail if -l is unset
    [ "$l" ] || { echo "ERROR" >&2; exit 128; }
    ;;
esac
# Maybe fail here if both -P and -l set?
```

Comment: If this doesn't solve your problem, maybe edit your question to explain in more detail what you actually want the code to do.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like that.

```
#!bin/bash

while getopts l:P:h: option
do
case "${option}"
in
l) arg1=${OPTARG};;
P) arg2=${OPTARG};;
h) arg3=${OPTARG};;
*)  echo "ERROR"
    exit 128
;;

esac
done
```